SQL 2012 Dynamic T-SQL code is not returning any data
I'm trying to create a trigger which will automatically store changes to any data as a string (but only the data that has changed - output would be {firstname:john,surname:doe}), this string would then be stored to a table.
As part for the trigger it would check the extended properties of the table and fields to see if they should be archived or not - ill worry about this bit later.
My problem appears to be that if I use dynamic code which is needed to loop and check the columns the INSERT/DELETE table access, the dynmic code creates a new 'context' and prevents access to the data.
I have left out all the other code because the stumbling block is this:
SET @ColumnNameI = 'i.[' + @ColumnName + ']';
SET @ColumnNameD = 'd.[' + @ColumnName + ']';

SELECT 
                    @ChangeDetails =  
                    CASE 
                        WHEN ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),  @ColumnNameI), '') != ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @ColumnNameD), '') 
                        THEN @ColumnNameI + ': OldValue = ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),  'd.' + @ColumnName), 'NULL') + ', NewValue = ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),  'i.' + @ColumnName), 'NULL') + '; ' 
                        ELSE 'NOTHING' 
                    END
                FROM ...

If instead of @ColunmNameI & D i use i/d.firstname it works but only provides information on the one column. As soon as I go dynamic in any way it fails including trying i.@ColumnName.
Is there way to have dynmaic code and still retain the information form INSERT/DELETE?
I had previously done this with a trigger calling an assembly which was nice and maintainable due to all the code in one place but I'm trying to move away from that method and soley into t-sql - is there a nice way of having triggers calling a single point of code instead of having to apply all the code to every trigger table.?

SQL Server already has auditing, change tracking and CDC features that are available to all supported versions and editions, even Express. Before 2016 SP1 some of these features were only available to Enterprise editions. SQL Server 2012 is completely out of support. It seems you're trying to do something already available in far better form.

Don't forget temporal tables too.

It's very inefficient to do this on every run of the trigger. And you can't use inserted and deleted with dynamic SQL anyway, so not sure what you hope to achieve with all this. Instead use a script to generate the trigger dynamically, but the trigger itself will be static.

Thanks both - both correct comments but this is for a particular project. Ill keep with the working CRL method for now.

Interpreting the audit trail may be a challenge when the columns contain values that look like audit entries. Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use QuoteName() to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. New Table with a space or reserved words like From. It does more than just add square brackets around any string. And see Is Distinct From.

When we did this, the first line of the trigger copied inserted/deleted into #inserted and #deleted, and then we worked on those temporary tables without losing context
